# how to fix pre tag in Response

Tags: php

I'm getting a response enclosed inside pre tag.(like)

> result..

Note:

> Getting response 200 ok. but the format is not correct

I saw the function which is responsible for getting values from server, with I went up to SQL query their also.

path :

> /widgets/?action=get-add-modal-content&dashboard-id=548&dashboard-type=user

result :

```
{"widgets_categories": ...}
```

code :

```
namespace Tuleap\Dashboard\User;

use Tuleap\Dashboard\DashboardPresenter;

class UserDashboardPresenter extends DashboardPresenter
{
    public $user_id;

    public function __construct(UserDashboard $dashboard, $is_active, array $widgets)
    {
        parent::__construct($dashboard, $is_active, $widgets);

        $this->user_id                = $dashboard->getUserId();
        $this->url_add_widget_content = '/widgets/?'. http_build_query(
            array(
                'action'         => 'get-add-modal-content',
                'dashboard-id'   => $this->id,
                'dashboard-type' => UserDashboardController::DASHBOARD_TYPE
            )
        );
        $this->url_add_widget = '/widgets/?'. http_build_query(
            array(
                'action'         => 'add-widget',
                'dashboard-id'   => $this->id,
                'dashboard-type' => UserDashboardController::DASHBOARD_TYPE
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I expecting JSON, but it returning string.

Comment: result : <pre>{"widgets_categories": ...} </pre>.   I can't able to figure it out, from where pre tag is coming.

Comment: search <pre> in your project. i thing you use this for debug and you forgot to remove

Comment: yes, I left pre tag at one place in my project after a long search I found it. Thank you Shanteshwar Inde

Comment: happy to help.!